# resume from Suspend causes graphics failure

Tags: graphics, suspend, dell, laptop

Following the recent version upgrade to 20.04.1 LTS from 18x, I am unable to resume operation immediately after a hard Suspend to Disk. The laptop goes through the re-loading process, but the entire screen displays a broken graphics image (like a static TV screen). When I type on this screen it appears to respond however the rendering never fully recovers and I have no idea what is going on from that point forward. I must cold boot at this point to continue. I can recover from soft Sleep mode just fine as before the upgrade.

I have a Dell Latitude E6510 laptop i7, NVA8 Graphics, 4GB RAM. This functionality always worked fine in 18.x.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. I changed the graphics driver to a proprietory NVIDIA one. Seemed to do the trick. However when I resume, my desktop background image is corrupt and I have to reload this. [GeForce 9600 GT]